# GGTS The project was not built since its build path is incomplete

Tags: java, git, grails

I am having problem running my grails application from grails GGTS IDE.

I had to format my harddisk so i had to reinstall all new software. I had a copy of Groovy/Grails Tool Suite. I didn't need to install it since it was stand alone so i just ran it. Since i didn't have java installed i installed jdk 1.8. so now in the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java i could see both jdk1.8.0_65 folder and jre1.8.0_65 folder.

Now i imported a git project by doing git clone from ggts. Now the final thing i did was that i went to  window > Preferences. There in Java > Installed JREs in the right side i clicked on Add.. chose standard VM and and clicked on Directory ... for JRE home and then located the jdk location. c:\program files(x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_65.

After following these steps i get the following error message.

"The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for groovy.lang.GroovyObject. Fix the build path then try building this project"

am i missing any other configurations? if so, please let me know. I appreciate your help!

Note: One thing i am noting is that when i go to properties of the project and select java build path and select libraries and there is JRE System Library [jdk1.8.0_65]. I expand it and there in Native library location i notice it has (None). Does this have anything to do with the errors i am getting?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to right-click on project and  "Grails Tool -> Refresh Dependencies"?

It's also possible to execute it from command line (confirmed on Ubuntu):

```
    grails compile --non-interactive --refresh-dependencies
```

Comment: i think the issue was that i had java 1.8 installed. I installed java 1.7 and it worked. thanks!